# Replace first match after a match with sed

Tags: bash, sed

what I want to achieve is to find an string in file and go on finding first occurrence of another match and replace that with some value.

Ex: string =  `{Name: name;Address:someadd;var1:var1;var2:var2},{Name: differntName;Address:someadd;var1:var1;var2:var2}`

Now what i need to do is to find Name: name and then find first occurrence of "var2:var2" after "Name: name" and replace it with "var2:newvarvalue"

Please note that i need to complete this task with sed in bash scripting.

Thanks in advance.

Edit : i am trying to modify .yaml docker compose file

Comment: `awk` might be a better option than `sed`

Comment: thanks @KindStranger for quick response, but i need to do this in sed, but i can consider awk once i ran out of options.

Comment: Is this JSON data? If so, you would do best to use `jq` or other specialized parser. It's the same argument as trying to parse HTML with regex ; sure you can handle basic use-cases just fine, but you will soon enough encounter an edge case that will make having used a specialized parser from the start a huge gain of time. Edit : it's not JSON data. The point to use a specialized parser if it exists still stands though

Comment: @vinay If this is yaml, I recommend to use a programming language that is able to parse and modify yaml. For example Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a terrible solution using `sed` :

1. split on `,`, one part per line :

`sed 's/,/\n/g'`

2. replace `var2:var2` by `var2:newvarvalue` if on the same line as `Name: name` :

`sed '/Name: name/s/var2:var2/var2:newvarvalue/'`

or

`sed -E 's/(Name: name.*)var2:var2/\1var2:newvarvalue/'`

It's terrible because any extra comma or linefeed might break the whole thing.

Comment: I forgot step 3) join back the lines together, but I guess this was obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
var='{Name: name;Address:somea,dd;var1:var1;var2:var2},{Name: differntName;Address:someadd;var1:var1;var2:var2}'

NEW_VAL='new_value'

IFS=$'\n'

OBJECTS=("$(echo "${var}" | sed -nE 's/[^{]*(\{[^}]+\})/\1\n/gp')")

for obj in "${OBJECTS[@]}"; do
  echo "${obj}" | sed -E 's/(.*var2:)(var2)(.*)/\1'"${NEW_VAL}"'\3/'
done
```

Output:

```
{Name: name;Address:somea,dd;var1:var1;var2:new_value}
{Name: differntName;Address:someadd;var1:var1;var2:new_value}
```

This solution accounts for a comma in the object *(as exemplified in the first object)* by extracting each and setting the delimiter to a newline.